# Callable class member detector idiom and C++11 final

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I would like to detect if a type is callable, the following works great for all classes that are not marked `final`:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_callable_impl {
 private:
  typedef char(&yes)[1];
  typedef char(&no)[2];

  struct fallback {
    void operator()();
  };
  struct derived
    : T, fallback {};

  template<typename U, U> struct check;

  template<typename>
  static yes test(...);

  template<typename C>
  static no test(check<void (fallback::*)(), &C::operator()>*);

 public:
   static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<derived>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template<typename T>
struct is_callable
: std::conditional<
    std::is_function<T>::value,
    std::true_type,
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_class<T>::value,
        is_callable_impl<T>,
        std::false_type
    >::type
>::type {};
```

This is the C++03 way member detector idiom but we can now use SFINAE expressions with `decltype`. I cannot work out how to detect *any* overloaded `operator()` on a type? The above uses a `fallback` to detect if there is no callable function pointer available on T.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633be750a3d6edce)

Comment: Just ignore that classes can be marked `final`.

Comment: @Xeo, but there are classes in a library that _are_ marked `final`, using `is_final` won't help me determine if that class is callable :(

Comment: It's better to create `is_callable<F, int(int)>` where `int(int)` is the signature you expect. Having an `is_callable` trait by itself is fairly useless. You want to know how you're going to call it and if it's possible.

Comment: That `is_callable` doesn't cope with overloads or templated `operator()` anyway.

Comment: @Puppy, OK. I guess this is looking for a solution to a problem from a problem. Time to go back a few steps. Thanks.

Comment: @puppy, it actually does work with overloads and template situations. Have updated the live demo.

Comment: @MattClarkson: Excuse me, but what good is detecting whether class is callable at all? You need to know whether it is callable with a specific set of arguments, no?

Comment: @n.m. use a function trait to inspect the return type and the arguments. This information is then used to cast an opaque variant to the correct type at a messaging end point. It allows the API to accept lambdas as `RegisterEndPoint(lambda)` rather than `RegisterLambda<MyType>(lambda)`. I guess I could make the function trait SFINAE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(is_callable, T::operator (), void (T::*)() const);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/nmplGs)